# how to create pagination with next and previous button?

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
<table>
    <tr style="background: white url(bg.gif) repeat-x left top;color: #fff;">
      <th>College Id</th>
      <th>College Name</th>
      <th>Website</th>
      <th>Field</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
      $per_page=10;
      if (isset($_GET["page"])) 
      {
      $page = $_GET["page"];
      }
      else {
      $page=1;
      }
      $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

      $sql="select * from all_colleges LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
      $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['college_id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['college_name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['website']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['field']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <a class='view' title='view' href='view.php?id=<?php echo $row['college_id']; ?>'>
          <img src='gridview/view.png' alt='view' />
        </a>

        <a class='update' title='Update' href='update.php?id=<?php echo $row['college_id']; ?>'>
          <img src='gridview/update.png' alt='Update' />
        </a>

        <a class='delete' title='delete' href='delete.php?ad_id=<?php echo $row['college_id']; ?>'>
          <img src='gridview/delete.png' alt='delete' />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
      }
    ?>
</table>

<div style="padding: 10px;">
  <?php
  $query = "select * from all_colleges";
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
  echo "<center><a href='admin.php?page=1' style='padding:5px;'>".'previous'."</a>";
  for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
  echo "<a href='admin.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
  }
  echo "<a href='admin.php?page=$total_pages'>".'next'."</a></center>";
  ?>
</div>
```

In this code I want to create a pagination with next and previous button here this code is working properly but it show diffrent pagination i.e. if the number of results is 200 then it will display like

```
previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 next
```

but I want like

```
previous 1 2 3 4 5 ....8 9 next
```

How can I do this please help ?

Thank You

Comment: Also, your `previous` and `next` appears to work as `first` and `last`. _(Just a note)_

Comment: yes, previous and next appears to work as first and last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check each iteration of your loop if you want to display the number.
In the following code, only:

- the first two pages
- the last two pages
- the current page
- each two pages to the left and to the right of the current page

are displayed.

```
$skipped = false;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)  {
    if ($i < 3 || $total_pages- $i < 3 || abs($page - $i) < 3) {
        if ($skipped)
            echo '<span> ... </span>';
        $skipped = false;
        echo "<a href='admin.php?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
    } else {
        $skipped = true;
    }
}
```

If you have **a lot of** pages, the big loop is unnecessary.
Instead, you could use three different loops:

```
$done = [];

for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $done[$i] = true;
    //echo 
}

if ($page > 3)
   echo '<span> ... </span>';

for ($i = $page - 2; $i < $page + 3; $i++) {
    if (isset($done[$i])
        continue;

    $done[$i] = true;
    //echo
}

if ($page < $total_pages - 3)
   echo '<span> ... </span>';

for ($i = $total_pages- 2; $i < $total_pages; $i++) {
    if (isset($done[$i])
        continue;

    $done[$i] = true;
    //echo
}
```

To fix your two other buttons (`previous` and `next`), link to `$page - 1` and`$page + 1` instead of `1` and `$total_pages`.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a different solution that is better if you have a lot of pages @kevin